# How to extract all types of nouns in Java?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to get all types of nouns from a text how can I get?

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;


public class Noun_Code {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{

            FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\NaB33L NaQ33B!\\Desktop\\TaggerDemo.java");
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

            String text = "";
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line!=null){
                text +=line;
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(text);
            String tagged;

            MaxentTagger LibAddress =  new MaxentTagger("F:\\stanford-postagger-2015-04-20\\stanford-postagger-2015-04-20\\models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger");
            tagged = LibAddress.tagString(text);

            System.out.println("Frequency : "+tagged);

            String[] words = tagged.split(" ");

            String[] keyword1 = new String[words.length];
            int len=keyword1.length;
        for(int i = 0;i<words.length;i++)
        {
            int length= words[i].length();
            char chr1 = (char) (words[i].charAt(length-3));
            char chr2 = (char) (words[i].charAt(length-2));
            char chr3 = (char) (words[i].charAt(length-1));
            if(chr1=='N' && chr2=='N' && chr3=='P')
            {
            keyword1[i] = words[i]; 
            System.out.println(keyword1[i]);
            }
            else
            {
            keyword1[i] = "-1";
            }
        }
            int var =0;
        for(int i = 0;i<keyword1.length;i++)
        {
            if(keyword1[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-1"))
            {
            var=var+1;
            }
        }
            len=len-var;
            String[] original = new String[len];
            String[] temp = new String[len];
            int e=0;
        for(int i = 0;i<keyword1.length;i++)
        {
            if(keyword1[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-1")){}
            else
            {original[e] = keyword1[i];
            temp[e] = keyword1[i];
            e=e+1;
            }
        }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){System.out.println("Exception :"+ex);}
}
}
```

Please guide me, to get all types of nouns. above is all the code which I am using. I want all the below noun types:
**Common noun**
A common noun is a noun that refers to people or things in general, e.g. boy, country, bridge, city, birth, day, happiness.

**Proper noun**
A proper noun is a name that identifies a particular person, place, or thing, e.g. Steven, Africa, London, Monday. In written English, proper nouns begin with capital letters.

**Concrete noun**
A concrete noun is a noun which refers to people and to things that exist physically and can be seen, touched, smelled, heard, or tasted. Examples include dog, building, coffee, tree, rain, beach, tune.

**Abstract noun**
An abstract noun is a noun which refers to ideas, qualities, and conditions - things that cannot be seen or touched and things which have no physical reality, e.g. truth, danger, happiness, time, friendship, humour.

**Collective nouns**
Collective nouns refer to groups of people or things, e.g. audience, family, government, team, jury. In American English, most collective nouns are treated as singular, with a singular verb: The whole family was at the table.

Comment: Properly ident and comment your code. It will help people understand it and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to get all the Nouns from a text; This code will extract all the Nouns having type NN, NNS, NNP, NNPS, PRP etc
Note: For this **OpenNLP** was used.
Here is the link of [Alphabetical list of part-of-speech tags used in the Penn Treebank Project](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html):

```
public void getNounPhrases(Parse p) {
        if (p.getType().equals("NN") || p.getType().equals("NNS") || p.getType().equals("NNP") || p.getType().equals("NNPS")|| p.getType().equals("PRP")) {
             nounPhrases.add(p.getCoveredText());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need a list of all existing nouns on the dictionary. Then, you just search for each of them on the string.

You can probably use the list in the link bellow. It contains 4554 nouns.

http://www.desiquintans.com/nounlist

Answer (score 0):

From eyeballing your current code, it looks as if it is only searching for tokens whose tag begins with the characters 'NNP' --these are proper nouns only. If you also want to include common nouns you should include any tokens whose tag begins with 'NN'. This will include concrete nouns, abstract nouns, collective nouns etc.

You can find the full tagset here: https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html